# Git, rewriting history of master branch and associated tags

Tags: git, tags, history, url-rewriting

I've just had my first experience with rewriting the history of one of my repos (using git-filter-branch). The problem is that the repo had several tags, which after rewriting seem to be completely disconnected from the resulted history. I think this is due to the fact that the history associated with the tags hasn't been rewritten, so they have to point to the old commits. So, what can I do to "apply" the tags on the new history. A little ASCII art, maybe it's easier to understand my question:

**Original repo:**

```
+  HEAD
|
|
+  TAG 0.2.0
|
|
+  TAG 0.1.0
|
|
+  Initial commit
```

**Repo structure reported by `gitk --all` after history rewrite:**

```
    +  HEAD
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    |
    +  Initial commit
+  HEAD
|
|
+  TAG 0.2.0
|
|
+  TAG 0.1.0
|
|
+  Initial commit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like the last step of this [procedure described here](http://fpereda.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/how-i-migrated-paludis-to-git/)

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline origin/releases |
  sed -n -e '/^\([0-9a-f]\{40\}\) Tag\( release\)\? \(.*\)/s--\3|\1|Tag release \3-p'
  > ~/paludis-git-tags

$ while read name msg head ; do
  git tag -m "${msg}" ${name} ${head} ;
  done < paludis-git-tags
```

The idea is to read tags from the old versions of the repositories, to re-apply them on the new history.

---

Note: in your original use of git-filter-branch, did you use the:

```
-- --all
```

?

> the `--` that separates filter-branch options from revision options, and the `--all` to rewrite all branches and tags.

It may have kept the tag in place on the new history (I have not tested it yet though)

Comment: Thanks VonC, I missed the `-- --all` part. Luckily I had a backup of the repository and tried again with the `--all` option and it worked as I wished.

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to **rewrite tags too**, e.g. (as [VonC said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138960/git-rewriting-history-of-master-branch-and-associated-tags/1139196#1139196)) by using `--all` option to rewrite all references.

If you have *annotated tags* (heavyweight tags) you have also to use `--tag-name-filter` option, e.g. as `--tag-name-filter cat`.  Note that you cannot rewrite signed tags!

Comment: Thanks Jakub, I didn't know about annotated and signed tags. Useful info. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a change that can be done with `git filter-branch`, then you can use `--tag-name-filter` as explained above.

If you want to do interactive rebasing though, you need something else.

Both things can be accomplished with `git rebasetags`

In case the rebase is interactive, you will be presented with a bash shell where you can make the changes. Upon exiting that shell, the tags will be restored.

[image]

From [this post](https://ownyourbits.com/2017/08/14/rebasing-in-git-without-losing-tags/)