# Git, edit root commit for all branches

Tags: git

I have to rewrite the history of my repository because it contains some credentials. As I have to amend the root commit I followed the instructions from [Git Faq](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitFaq#How_do_I_edit_the_root_commit.3F):

> `git rebase -i` allows you to conveniently edit any previous commits, except for the root commit. The following commands show you how to do this manually.
>
> ```bash
> # tag the old root
> git tag root `git rev-list HEAD | tail -1`
> git checkout -b new-root root
> # edit...
> git commit --amend
>
> # check out the previous branch
> git checkout @{-1}
> # replace old root with amended version
> git rebase --onto new-root root
>
> # cleanup
> git branch -d new-root
> git tag -d root
> ```

My problem is though that I have two branches and several tags already in the repository and I'd like that my history rewrite to apply to those too. The repo isn't public yet, so that wouldn't be a problem. I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138960/git-rewriting-history-of-master-branch-and-associated-tags) before, but in that case the `git rebase` command was not used. Here's a basic graph of my repo:

```
+  master branch
|
|   + topic branch
|   |
|   |
+---+
|
|
|
+  TAG
|
+  Initial commit, the commit I'd like to amend for all branches
```

Is it even possible?

Comment: Possibly related: [Edit/amend/modify/change the first/root/initial commit in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2119480/456814).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **"[git filter-branch](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch)"** instead of git-rebase.

If you really, really feel that rebase would be better, with modern git you can use **`--root`** option to git-rebase.  Or cherry-pick root commit, and then rebase on top of it, if you have older git that doesn't have this option.

Comment: Thanks Jakub. But I'm not really sure how `filter-branch` will help me. I have to edit code in almost 10 files, so that I pretend that the first commit had no credentials in it. I don't know how would that be possible because there's no standard format for those files. It's just code. I think it would be possible using `--tree-filter`, but seems way to complicated to parse the code.

Comment: If that is the situation, simplest solution would be to create new empty branch (`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/new && rm -f .git/index`), and either cherry-pick root commit onto that branch and edit it using `git commit --amend`, then rebase rest, or use `git rebase --interactive --root --onto new master`. HTH.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try them both, although the second option seems easier. Greatly appreciated.