# Delete/reset a remote master Git repo

Tags: git

We have an Assembla remote repo.  Assembla doesn't offer free private repos now, so we want to re-use one of our old ones.  The repo has a master branch and a lot of files/commits.

How can we get rid of everything, including all files and history, to allow us to start again with a new project?

First I have an up-to-date pull of the repo.

I tried deleting the remote master branch thusly:

```
git push origin :master.
```

This gives the error :

> remote: error: By default, deleting the current branch is denied, because the next
>   remote: error: 'git clone' won't result in any file checked out, causing confusion.

So I tried creating a new branch, pushing it, then from the other branch deleting master, thusly:

```
git checkout -b tempy
git push origin tempy
git push origin :master
```

I get the same error.

I could switch back to master, delete all the files locally, then commit and push, but his leaves a lot of unwanted history.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest answer is to **remove/delete** your current project and **start a new one**.

OR the only other way would be to `force` a push

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote add origin <your-assembla-git-url>
git push -u --force origin master
```

Comment: By project, do you mean repo?   I cant delete the repo, as assmebla.com doesnt allow you to create new ones any more (well ti does, but only with 2 users).  I just need a way of deleting the files and idealiy history.  One can usually delete remote branches, so I thought I could delete the master branch, but it seems this is not allowed.

Comment: @JohnLittle I have updated my answer, this will remove your history and push a blank one up there.

Comment: Hi Oliver, tried you solution.  When try and push, says "remote error: denying non-fast-forward refs/heads/master (you should pull first)...! [remote rejected] master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed to push some refst to 'git@...  Any suggestions appreciated...

Comment: HAHA, it works! there is a setting in assembla.com which is "allow --force push".  Ticked this and it worked!  Back to a bare repo.  Oliver is the git God.  Am writing this recipe down!

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard <commit> # where commit is SHA of first commit in history
git push origin master
```

or remove `.git` completely from your local repo and redo `git init`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502899/368552