# Wipe directory history from SourceTree and start from scratch

Tags: git, bitbucket, sourcetree

Yesterday I created a directory called "project" with a WordPress install. This was added as an existing local repository via SourceTree and pushed to Bitbucket. Throughout the course of the day, I made further pushes.

Today I deleted the repository via Bitbucket and SourceTree as I'd like to start from scratch.

Is it possible to make SourceTree forget the directory / files, repository history and start as if it were a brand new project?

The WordPress "project" directory hasn't changed its name or files since the last push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to reset to your first commit and then do a force push.  [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499908/how-to-roll-back-git-repo-to-first-commit-and-delete-all-history) a link to an SO post that explains it well.