# How can I move all commits to another branch?

Tags: git

I am working on project alone (though some other people may use this repo) and for some time, I was making all my commits into `master` branch (commits are pushed to GitHub).

But at this point, I decided that `master` branch became too cluttered with small commits and, to make things look prettier, I want to move all my commit history into `wip` branch, and then only merge with `master` on new version.

The end result should be a `wip` branch with contents and commit history identical to the current `master` branch, and a `master` branch with a single commit with contents identical to the current `wip` branch.

What is the safest way to do that?

Comment: What do you want `master` to look like when you "merge with `master` on a new version"?  Will it be identical to `wip` with all the small commits?  Or do you intend to have a single squashed commit for that version?

Comment: The second, i want `master` to have single commit identical to latest `wip` stage at this moment.

Comment: I updated your question to add your desired end result, based on this comment.  (If I'm interpreting it wrong, obviously please feel free to fix it).

Answer (score 3):

You can start by creating `wip` from your current `master` history:

```
git switch -c wip master
```

From there, you can work on `wip` branch, then merge on `master` when ready.

> I also want to clear history on master

You can then `reset --hard` your `master` to an older commit, or all the [way back to the first commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16500248/6309), and force push it (assuming you have notified other users of the repository).

Comment: Thanks for answer. I also want to clear history on master.

Comment: @Agr OK, I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Are there any possible side-effects for others, if i do hard reset and then merge from my wip branch?

Comment: @Agr See this answer to [What are the practical consequences of rewriting Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1491022/6868543)

Comment: @j6t Yes: other needs to fetch and reset their own master branch to yours. They also need to isolate their work in their own branch.

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to rename the current `master` branch to `wip`, then create a new empty `master` branch.  Groups of commits could then be copied over to the new `master` branch from `wip`, combined into single commits in the new `master`.

```bash
# Rename the master branch to "wip" locally
git branch -m master wip

# Rename the remote master branch to "wip"
git push origin -d master
git push origin -u wip

# Check out a new, empty branch as master
git checkout --orphan master
git reset --hard

# Create a squashed commit matching the current state of wip
git checkout wip -- .
git add .
git commit

# Push the new master
git push origin -u master
```

### Detailed explanation

Use the [branch move](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m) option to rename the branch locally:

```bash
git branch -m master wip
```

Delete the remote branch using the [push delete](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--d) option, then add a new remote branch matching the local `wip` branch using the [push upstream](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) option:

```bash
git push origin -d master
git push origin -u wip
```

Create a new empty branch with no commit history.  This is done by creating an orphan branch (one without any commits) using the
[checkout orphan](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt---orphanltnewbranchgt) option.  The existing files will remain (uncommitted), so delete them using the [reset hard](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset#Documentation/git-reset.txt---hard) option:

```bash
git checkout --orphan master
git reset --hard
```

Copy the current state of the `wip` branch to the `master` branch.  First, copy all files from the `wip` branch by using the [checkout with pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-f--ours--theirs-m--conflictltstylegtlttree-ishgt--pathspec-from-fileltfilegt--pathspec-file-nul) option with the current working directory [pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#Documentation/gitglossary.txt-aiddefpathspecapathspec) (`.`) to recursively include all files in the current working directory.  These files are all added to the index using the [add with pathspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt-ltpathspecgt82308203) option with the current working directory pathspec.  Finally, a single commit with all these files is created using the [commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) option:

```bash
git checkout wip -- .
git add .
git commit
```

Finally, the new `master` branch is pushed to the origin using the [push upstream](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt--u) option:

```bash
git push origin -u master
```

Comment: I thought about orphan branch but decided to not recommend that approach. That way, wip and master keep a common history (from at least the first commit)

Comment: @VonC True, but the asker appears to not want a common history, but instead have different, larger-grained commits.  There are definitely benefits to the common history approach, though.

Comment: Though I could be misinterpreting.  I'll ask.