# How delete all repository history while keeping the changes?

Tags: git, repository

The file of my repository is very large. I am sure that I don't want to revert any previous commit, meaning all changes that have been done are wanted to be kept for good in the code. I just want to delete all the previous history while keeping the changes in place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to roll back Git repo to first commit and delete all history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16499908/how-to-roll-back-git-repo-to-first-commit-and-delete-all-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just delete the `.git` folder and then reinitialize the repo with `git init`.

On Windows, this can be done with `rmdir /s .git`

Comment: How to do this in Git Desktop Application?

Comment: I couldn't find a .git file, there're a bunch of IPCH files, .gitignore, .gitattributes, .editorconfig, and two Windows Batch Files

Comment: It's a hidden directory. You can do it from the terminal with `rmdir /s .git`