# How to undo last commit

Tags: git

I did the following comments

```
git add /file1/path
git rm /file/path
git commit -m "message"
```

how do I undo my last commit using git?

Like I don't want to have those files committed.

Comment: You've got the answer here, after a 2sec search... ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/a/927386/1266697

Comment: I'm unhappy with these questions and answers. They're often very vague. Does the user wish to simply undo the `git commit` (and leave the working tree unmodified?), or do they wish to also revert the working tree?

Comment: Explained in < 5 minutes in this video, if you prefer that format: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eg2xt-JoPfI&t=2s

Answer (score 381, accepted):

**Warning: Don't do this if you've already pushed**

You want to do:

```
git reset HEAD~
```

If you don't want the changes and blow everything away:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~
```

Comment: Dont do this if you already pushed

Comment: @ArnoldRoa Why? Can you expand?

Comment: Please edit your answer, you just cost me a lot of files. I thought you meant remove all of GIT while trying to set up a new repository... Wow.

Comment: I do have a lack of understanding about git, but use it very often. I doubt I was the first, there should be a warning on the answer for idiots like me.

I only wanted to reset git, not lose my directory (I had no prior commit to retrieve).

Comment: Doesn't work `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions`

Comment: @Green That error occurs when there's only single commit. In that case, its just easier to rm -rf the .git directory and create new repository from scratch.

Comment: "Don't do this if you've already pushed" - Why not? If you don't explain the intent, comments like that are what lead to crazy dogmas.

Comment: @Pharap then git revert is the way to do it. See [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa]

Comment: @Fookiee The effects are different though. That adds a new commit over top rather than deleting an old commit. That does not explain why deleting an already pushed commit is bad.

Comment: @Pharap Correct. Deleting an already pushed commit is bad when you are not the only contributor. Someone else - or a Service/Bot/Script - may have seen that commit already. After you have pushed some changes, the changes may be already "used" by someone else. When you add a new commit reverting something everyone will understand, that this is a later change.

Comment: @Fookiee But if the commit is already in the remote repository, your push will just fail and you will need to pull first, right?

Comment: @johndodo that depends on your remote server and user privileges. Many allow a push -f

Comment: # DON'T USE THIS, YOU WILL LOOSE EVERYTHING

Comment: I just used this and I didn't lose everything. If you're not sure what you're doing, you can always make a copy of your `.git` folder. The accepted answer to the suggested duplicate question is much more useful

Comment: @Green See answers at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632191/how-to-revert-initial-git-commit