# How can I undo pushed commits using git?

Tags: git

I have a project in a remote repository, synchronized with a local repository (development) and the server one (prod). I've been making some commited changes already pushed to remote and pulled from the server. Now, I want to undo those changes. So I could just `git checkout` to the commit before the changes and commit the new changes, but I'm guessing that there will be problems to push them again to remote. Any suggestion on how should I proceed?

Answer (score 1751, accepted):

You can revert individual commits with:

```bash
git revert <commit_hash>
```

This will create a new commit which reverts the changes of the commit you specified. Note that it only reverts that specific commit, and not commits that come after that. If you want to revert a range of commits, you can do it like this:

```bash
git revert <oldest_commit_hash>..<latest_commit_hash>
```

It reverts all the commits after `<oldest_commit_hash>` up to and including `<latest_commit_hash>`. Some versions of git also revert the `<oldest_commit_hash>` itself, so double check if that commit gets reverted or not. You can always drop the latest revert commit (which reverts the oldest commit) with `g reset --hard HEAD~`.

To find out the hash of the commit(s) you can use `git log`.

Look at the [git-revert man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) for more information about the `git revert` command. Also, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/1248175) for more information about reverting commits.

#### Extra note for re-applying reverted commits:

Usually you revert commits because you discovered the commits that you pushed turn out to have an issue. Then you first want to restore the repo to a stable state, before you continue to fix the issue. So then you would first do the `git revert`, as described before. Then push those revert commits, so the remote is stable. After that you would want to re-apply the reverted commits locally, so your local repo's files are back to the state before the revert. Then you can fix the issue.

To re-apply the reverted commits, you have to *revert* the *revert commits*. So what you would do, is to again execute the `git revert` command, but then with the range of commits of the **revert commits**. So your new revert commits will revert the previous revert commits. Then your files are back to the state before the first revert. Then you can fix the issue, create a new commit with the fix, and then push the new commits.

Comment: In other words it reverts to the <oldest_commit_hash> ;)

Comment: No info about how to get commit_hash. -1

Comment: @rednaw I know, I googled it. git rev-parse HEAD shows hash of the latest commit, so it's even better. Could you update your answer with that info?

Comment: @mr_jigsaw We have other SO questions for that ;)

Comment: In git documentation, it says that revert command reverts commits between first and last commits (both first and last included).  [See Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Comment: @aod is correct, this answer needs to be updated.  the current git API for revert has `<oldest_commit_hash>` being included in the list of reverts

Comment: with git 2.17.2 revert <old>..<new> does not include old but includes <new>

Comment: revert gives me `error: commit zzz is a merge but no -m option was given. fatal: revert failed`

Comment: @weber A merge commit consists of 2 commits, the ones that are merged together. So if you want to revert a merge commit, you have to specify which of the 2 merged commits you want to revert. You do this with the `-m` option. Check `git revert --help` for more info.

Comment: I just tried `git revert 9d50f5bdffd2c0bb0088c936cfc73b0a66a49d40..4b0a43e1cd24ff41eb521b97c5cf9e10dc2544bc` on my code and it only reverted the last one of the 3 in this range!

Comment: just tried....final step is missed, after  **"git revert <commit_hash>"** use **"git push origin <your_Branch>"**

Comment: The revert does not include the `oldest_commit_hash`, only the following commuts (up to and including `latest_commit_hash`). Could you update your answer?

Comment: @AronFiechter Thanks, updated the answer to not including `<oldest_commit_hash>` but added a note that on some versions of git it does include it, because some people seem to report that it does include it for them. I can't find anything about it in the git changelog about this, so not sure if it has to do with a git version or git config or something else.

Comment: I tried this. it, unfortunately, reverted the changes in my local machine and kept the remote unchanged

Comment: Hi @selmanioui after that, have you pushed that revert?

Comment: @Quimbo I haven't, because in my case I wanted to revert the pushed commit that's on the remote, if I do that, then all my work that's been pushed to the remote would've been gone. What I wanted was to only commit part of the changes that I made in the local to the remote, and the other part would only exist on my local. If I push the revert as you asked I would be losing the work from both my local and remote repos.

Comment: To discover the hash of your last commit use `git log -1`

Comment: This only reverted my last commit, then I found out I had to do `git revert --continue`. The problem is that the process looks never ending, is there a way to make it continue alone? I don't see any purpose, git already knows how the repository will look like after the process

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina I think it's best if you open a new question for this, describing your problem more verbosely, so people can help you better.

Answer (score 806):

A solution that keeps no traces of the "undo".

NOTE: Don't do this if someone already pulled your change
(I would use this only on my personal repo.)

Run:

```
git reset <previous label or sha1>
```

Note: *previous* means the commit *before* the erroneous commit

This will re-checkout all the updates locally (so `git status` will list all updated files, meaning, the files you changed/added/.. and were committed).

Then you "do your work" and re-commit your changes (Note: This step is optional).

```
git commit -am "blabla"
```

At this moment your local tree differs from the remote

```
git push -f <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

will force the remote branch to take this push and remove the previous one (specifying remote-name and branch-name is not mandatory but is recommended to avoid updating all branches with update flag).

!! Watch-out some tags may still be pointing removed commit !! [how-to-delete-a-remote-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480258/how-to-delete-a-remote-tag)

Comment: thank but could u tell me why -am? what does it do? cant I do it without "-am"?

Comment: -a   all tracked files will be commited  
-m  commit message follows

Comment: Exactly what I searched for. Somebody did a faulty commit and push and reverted it again afterwards. The branches could not be merged because of this and I wanted to get the repository to be in the correct state again (and removing the commit from history as they were faulty ones anyway)

Comment: Which "previous label or sha1" should I use?. Should I enter the last "correct" one or the one before that and re-do all the changes done by the last correct one?

Comment: the one just before the eroneous commit

Comment: Is the commit needed? Can't I just do a reset and force push it?

Comment: yes you don't need to commit , just need to "push -f" to undo the previously pushed commit. (thanks vrwim I updated the post )

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me, I ended up with a `fatal: You are not currently on a branch.` error when trying to `git push -f`.

Comment: @Zabri : is the commit you want to undo on the head of a branch ? (the answer must be yes to use this solution)

Comment: Exactly what I need. I've pushed a branch to master by mistake. And as a result I had many rubbish commits during all commits history. I just done `git push -f` for last correct commit and remote history cleaned up! Thanks!

Comment: can the author or community provide some valid scenarios where deleting the commit from the remote is "needed" instead of just "wanted"? sounds like 'byemute' has at least one valid scenario. but i would be interest to hear other scenarios.

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith: This can have side effect this is why I started with a Note. But some times you are requested to have a clean repository thus removing an unwanted commit or re-organizing the commits is required.

Comment: @jo_ you should add that the `git push -f` will force push other branches you have out of sync with origin. I had 2 other branches that were not synched with origin that got forced:
```develop -> develop (forced update)
dusk/donation-tests -> dusk/donation-tests (forced update)
hotfix/donation-update -> hotfix/donation-update (forced update)
```

Comment: @JonTroncoso, sorry for the inconvenience; I updated the post.

Comment: @jo_ its ok... was more about being informative then gripes about what i did. :)

Comment: You are the best the best

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` will do for the first step if it's just the last commit you want to undo. Saves trying to figure out the right "previous label or sha1".

Answer (score 490):

What I do in these cases is:

- In the server, move the cursor back to the last known good commit:

  ```
  git push -f origin <last_known_good_commit>:<branch_name>
  ```
- Locally, do the same:

  ```
  git reset --hard <last_known_good_commit>
  #         ^^^^^^
  #         optional
  ```

---

---

---

See a full example on a branch `my_new_branch` that I created for this purpose:

```
$ git branch
my_new_branch
```

This is the recent history after adding some stuff to `myfile.py`:

```
$ git log
commit 80143bcaaca77963a47c211a9cbe664d5448d546
Author: me
Date:   Wed Mar 23 12:48:03 2016 +0100

    Adding new stuff in myfile.py

commit b4zad078237fa48746a4feb6517fa409f6bf238e
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 18 12:46:59 2016 +0100

    Initial commit
```

I want to get rid of the last commit, which was already pushed, so I run:

```
$ git push -f origin b4zad078237fa48746a4feb6517fa409f6bf238e:my_new_branch
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:me/myrepo.git
 + 80143bc...b4zad07 b4zad078237fa48746a4feb6517fa409f6bf238e -> my_new_branch (forced update)
```

Nice! Now I see the file that was changed on that commit (`myfile.py`) shows in "not staged for commit":

```
$ git status
On branch my_new_branch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/my_new_branch'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   myfile.py

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Since I don't want these changes, I just move the cursor back locally as well:

```
$ git reset --hard b4zad078237fa48746a4feb6517fa409f6bf238e
HEAD is now at b4zad07 Initial commit
```

So now HEAD is in the previous commit, both in local and remote:

```
$ git log
commit b4zad078237fa48746a4feb6517fa409f6bf238e
Author: me
Date:   Tue Mar 18 12:46:59 2016 +0100

    Initial commit
```

Comment: This is the correct answer! It is regarding pushed(!) commits!

Comment: If you want to truly revert changes (as if you've never pushed them), this _is_ the correct answer.

Comment: This has worked for me, too (as if I've never pushed them :))

Comment: what if my repo has only 1 commit pushed to server and i want to revert it? your answer is dependent on having a `last_known_good_commit` but i don't have any

Comment: @anshsachdeva mmm good question. Wouldn't it be faster to just remove the repo and create it over again?

Comment: @fedorqui yes i know. was just asking if nuking the repo would be the correct way to handle this situation

Comment: git push -f origin <last_known_good_commit>:<branch_name> 
for the devops/lead dev - constantly hotfixing -  crazy people like me this is literally is the most awesome git command I have ever seen, thanks

Comment: If you really don't know where the last know good commit was, you might want to take a look at git bisect.

Comment: The change i did was indeed undone, but the commit (along with the commit message) still appears in the "commits" tab in Git.

Comment: ```git reset HEAD~``` Will reset the last commit locally without getting rid of your changes

Comment: Beware of the last good commit hash you decide to work with. Say you are in your local user branch and the last good commit hash you chose is not from your branch then all the existing changes in your branch will be erased or over written by the files available in the branch's commit hash you chose. So make sure the last commit id you decide to reset is from your current working local branch.

Comment: I like this answer! Thanks!

I should point out that adding --hard on the git reset command will discard the local changes. So just do 'git reset <previous hash>' to preserve the changes. The changes will be unstaged.

Comment: I always forget that `git reset --hard` removes all working tree/local changes. It is half clear in the text, maybe make it even more clear? (I e "Warning, this will remove all uncommitted edits in your working tree (i e local catalogue)" or something. )

If I want to keep my local changes, lets say I am undoing a commit to a wrong branch or something, so I want to keep edits in my local catalogue, then `git reset --soft <hash>` would be better for that usecase, I think.

Comment: @MarcusWiderberg feel free to suggest an improvement!

Answer (score 286):

This will remove your pushed commits

```
git reset --hard 'xxxxx'

git clean -f -d

git push -f
```

Make a backup just in case

Two notes bumped up from comments:

- `'xxxxx'` is the hash code of the last commit that you want to keep.
- `clean` is dangerous. It removes files, not under version control!

Comment: This method properly rewrites the history to delete the commit. Awesome

Comment: Just to be clear (I wasn't sure): The commit will be the current commit after the operation.  Not the last one to delete.

Comment: warning: I accidentally reverted to PARENT (instead of COMMIT), be careful about that :)

Comment: I've come here looking for this answer. Although it may seem correct be cautious with this solution as it may break co-workers' environments. It's unadviced to erase common branches history. Use this only when you are certain nobody's going to be affected.

Comment: if  you would  like to keep ur  changes  locally  please use  `git reset --soft 'xxxxx' ` and  keep using remained  commands !

Comment: This erased my unstaged changes. sigh.

Comment: Is 'xxxxx' the hash of the commit?

Comment: @DavidKlempfner yes, it's the git commit unique id. replace 'xxxxx' with something like abc8039b

Comment: `clean` is dangerous. It removes files, which not under version control!

Comment: _'xxxxx'_ is the hash code of the last commit that you want to keep.

Comment: be careful with `clean`

Comment: even though it seems to be a dangerous solution, works like a charm

Answer (score 132):

You can REVERT (or you can also call it *DELETE*) the Git Commit **BOTH Locally and Remotely** if you follow the steps as given below via git command line.

Run the following command to see the commit id that you want to revert

```
git log --oneline --decorate --graph
```

You will get like a following screenshot
[image]

If you also check remote **(via Web Interface)** then you can see that this would be same as shown below

[image]

As per screenshot currently you are on commit id **e110322** however you want to revert back to **030bbf6** BOTH **LOCALLY and REMOTELY**.

**Perform the following steps to DELETE/REVERT Commits Locally+Remotely**

---

First Locally Reverting to commit id **030bbf6**

```
git reset --hard 030bbf6
```

followed by

```
git clean -f -d
```

These two commands clean force reset to commit stage **030bbf6** as shown below in snapshot

### [image]

now if you run 
git status then you'll see that you are TWO Commits BEHIND from the remote branch as shown below
[image]

Run following to update your indexes (if there are any updates). It is recommended that you ask all developers not to accept any pull requests on main remote branch.

```
git fetch --all
```

Once you are done with it then you are required to **Push** this commit **forcefully** by using **+** symbol in-front of branch as shown below. I have used here as *master* branch, you can replace it with any

[image]
Code

```
git push -u origin +master
```

now if you see the web interface of remote then commit there should be reverted as well.

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer on here, because it actually explains with an example! Thanks for that. However, I get the following error:  ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'gitlab.com:information-provision/collectors/deribit-collector.git'  Despite having maintainer status etc

Comment: @user6400946 are you using '+' (plus) symbol as shown in the last command ?
`git push -u origin +YourBrandName`

Comment: Yes, howeverI just solved it. It seems my master branch was protected from force push and I needed to unprotect it temporarily (under gitlab repository settings).

Comment: This should be documented

Comment: 2023 and this is proper solution for me

Answer (score 124):

Let's say `61234` is the sha-number of the last good commit you want to keep.

```
git reset --hard 61234
git push -f
```

will remove completely all wrong commits without any trace.

Note: If you wanted to push (the commit you reset to) to a specific branch you'd use `git push -f origin branch-name` instead.

Comment: Thank you! And the commit history is innocent! To convenient getting sha-number I've used:

$ git log --oneline <feature-branch-name>.

Comment: I got `remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project.` error for running `git push -f origin master`. I think I have to change some configuration on my gitlab server.

Comment: I edited your answer because I almost ran `git push -f origin master` when I really wanted to reset a commit on a branch – glad it didn't go!

Comment: I'm like you , always need push-back ,  use this way :
git reset --hard <last-good-commit-hash>    and after
git push -f origin branch-name

Answer (score 59):

**2020 Simple way :**

```
git reset <commit_hash>
```

(The hash of the last commit you want to keep).

You will keep the now uncommitted changes locally.

If you want to push again, you have to do :

```
git push -f
```

Comment: It does not work always as the admin can block re-write history which is very common in the industry. So the solution mentioned by @gitaarik will work.
git revert <commit_hash>
git push origin <branch_name>

Answer (score 36):

```
git revert HEAD -m 1
```

In the above code line. "Last argument represents"

- 1 - reverts one commits.
- 2 - reverts last two commits.
- n - reverts last n
  commits.

You need to push after this command to take the effect on remote. You have other options like specifying the range of commits to revert. This is one of the option.

---

Later use `git commit -am "COMMIT_MESSAGE"`
then `git push` or `git push -f`

Comment: This is not true - the -m parameter specifies number of parent to revert to (typically 1 if you want to revert the incoming, "theirs", changes, as opposed to 2 for merged-to changes, "ours" - for merging 2 commits). It has nothing to do with number of commits reverted - if you want to revert a commit range, use `git revert ref1..ref2`

Comment: Didn't have the desired effect

Answer (score 27):

Here is my way:

Let's say the branch name is `develop`.

```bash
# Checkout a new temp branch based on one history commit
# (command to get history commit hashes: git log --oneline)
git checkout <last_known_good_commit_hash>

# Delete the original develop branch 
git branch -D develop
# Create a new develop branch based on the temp branch
git checkout -b develop

# Force update the remote with the new branch
git push -f origin develop
```

Comment: I faced with illegal symbols on mac and only this solution helped me save the project.

Comment: It seems too risky to delete the develop branch just to undo a commit. What if it's a very busy project?

Comment: @Nikita128 You are right, if it's a very busy project and this method will remove others commits for sure.

Comment: @Nikita128 It keeps old history intact. And you can keep a backup branch, just in case. But for me, this works like a charms. Other answers, keeps the deleted commits in history and I have to pull them again.

Answer (score 19):

The reset hard worked for me:
Thanks @[Mo D Genensis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5517161/mo-d-genesis) and @[vibs2006](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436594/vibs2006)

```
git reset --hard 'your last working commit hash'

git clean -f -d

git push -f
```

Comment: This overrides the files that are changed and deletes the files that are added.

Comment: This seems a duplicate of Mo D Genesis answer.

Answer (score 12):

There are a number of ways like moving back commits by using `git reset HEAD^`, adding a `^` for every commit you want to go back, problem is the changes after that commit are then lost and can be added in a new commit. So I only do this when I only have to go one or two commits back.

To do it cleanly use the following:

```bash
git rebase -i <hash of last good commit, 9 chars is enough>
```

Now you will get a list of the commits from the last good commit to the `HEAD` with options what to do with each commit, going from the most recent at the top to the one just before the commit of the hash you added to the command. It will look something like this:

[image]

You can change the `pick` before every commit to any of the other options in the list of options. `drop` for instance, will remove the commit. You then save the file and the commits will be reapplied, performing the option you chose for every commit.

Now to fix the upstream do :

```
git push --force-with-lease
```

([With lease](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---no-force-with-lease) so you don't accidentally cause problems for someone else working on your pushed update)

This keeps the log clean by removing the wrong commit instead of introducing new commits fixing earlier erroneous commits.

[edit]: More clarification. And image example

Comment: This doesn't work as it creates a diverged branch and you can't push it (not even with -force). But would be the nicest solution if it was working...

Comment: @rimes, I have used this type of construction, perhaps not often but, a number of times on code meant for production. A colleague (our resident git guru) uses it to squash code from PR's with a large number of commits to combine commits and keep the master branch log clean.

Answer (score 10):

TL;DR

1. `git reset HEAD~1`
   – to go back 1 commit keeping all the changes in the working directory
2. `git status` will show you the changes kept
3. `git add ...`
4. `git commit`
5. `git push --force-with-lease` – to overwrite the original erroneous commit

Comment: `git reset` is the same as `git reset --mixed` = it undoes the previous `git commit` and also the previous `git add`.

Answer (score 7):

`git reset <commit_hash>` (to get the<commit_hash> use git log --oneline)

`git restore .`  to restore all the changed files to the version of yout target commit

`git push origin master --force` to force the push to your remote master branch. But be careful when using the force push if there is anyone working with you in the same branch

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
git push origin +<short_commit_sha>^:<branch_name>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the +,^ and : characters in the command?

Answer (score 0):

1. You should have a default git editor that works, you can set it as notepad++, vscode or whatever you want.
2. You need your commit hash, you can create a git alias named git lg, it will show you the list of your commit information, there is the command

```bash
git config --global alias.lg "log --color --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit --"
```

3. follow these step

NOTE: If you want to delete the first commit, you cannot use these steps.

```bash
git lg
```

[image]

```bash
 git rebase -i <commit-hash>
```

IMPORTANT: If i want to delete commit: '43a8b12 Implement XYZ feature' I should use the commit hash of the previous commit so there it is: `git rebase -i f96b5a9`

[image]

- Replace pick with d or drop. Save your changes & close the editor.

```bash
 git push --force-with-lease
```

If something is wrong or you cannot do it feel free to reply to this post, I will help you with love :)

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~<number of commits to undo>
git push origin +<name of branch>
```

Helped me remove the commits and push from GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in the downstream (local) branch of the remote branch that you need to modify, use the following two commands to undo the last commit and push the updated history to the remote: `git reset --hard HEAD~1` `git push -f`

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do this without revert (traces of undo):

**Don't do it if someone else has pushed other commits**

Create a backup of your branch, being in your branch `my-branch`. So in case something goes wrong, you can restart the process without losing any work done.

```sh
git checkout -b my-branch-temp
```

Go back to your branch.

```sh
git checkout my-branch
```

Reset, to discard your last commit (to undo it):

```sh
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

Remove the branch on remote (ex. `origin` remote).

```sh
git push origin :my-branch
```

Repush your branch (without the unwanted commit) to the remote.

```sh
git push origin my-branch
```

Done!

I hope that helps! ;)