# How to uncommit code on master

Tags: git, bash, github

I have mistakenly committed code and pushed it to master from GIT Bash, instead of doing commit new code to new branches, then merge to the master branch.

How can I undo my commit to the master branch. I have the HEAD at 40b66b17

Tried below options:

```
<MY_ID>@<Machine> MINGW32 /c (master)
$ git reset --hard 40b66b17
HEAD is now at 40b66b1 Add Components draft 



<MY_ID>@<Machine> MINGW32 /c (master)
$ git push -f origin master

Everything up-to-date


<MY_ID>@<Machine> MINGW32 /c (master)
$ git show ORIG_HEAD
commit 40b66b17540f0ac5aa6ec83b8c843b7e9674e063
Author: My Name <My Email Id>
Date:   Wed Feb 17 11:14:17 2016 -0600

    Add Components draft 

diff --git a/File1 b/File2
new file mode 100644
```

Still when I see the current HEAD pointer, it is showing at the same place. I want to have my master clean without any commits. My apologies with terminology here. As I am new to GIT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Undo pushed commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well if you have already pushed it, and others may have already pulled since then, I would recommend **not** doing any history rewriting, such as `git reset`. However, if you are the only one that uses the repo or you are **sure** nobody has pulled since your last push, do:

```
git checkout master
git reset --soft head~
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
git commit -m "My message"
git checkout master
git push -f
```

This will move your last commit from `master` to `my-feature-branch`.

Now, if you are not sure if someone might have already pulled your commit, the safest thing would be to just undo the *effects* of your commit. Do that with:

```
git revert HEAD
git push
git checkout -b my-feature-branch
git cherry-pick HEAD~
```

Comment: when I did $ git fetch origin master, FETCH_HEAD is showing at master. Does PUSH at this point makes my master repository clean?

Comment: When I am doing git reset --soft head~ I am getting error fatal: ambiguous argument 'head~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: @NagaVemprala, that is really bizarre; the only way I can see that happening is if you were on the very first commit of a repo. How many commits do you see if you do `git log --oneline`?

Comment: There are two commits.  $ git log --oneline
b342c4b Revert "Add Components draft" Reverting back commit to master This reverts commit 40b66b17540f0ac5aa6ec83b8c843b7e9674e063.
40b66b1 Add Components draft

Comment: I think the commit b342c4b is added when I typed the first command itself "git revert HEAD"

Comment: @NagaVemprala - So it sounds as if the "Add Components draft" was the very first commit on this repo, you tried the `git reset` solution, got the error, then tried the `git revert` solution, and then did `git log`. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes David. I got some error with git reset. Then tried git revert HEAD. It asked me to type a comment. Then gave a comment to revert the changes. After that tried git push. Got error again that "You are not allowed to push code to protected branches on this project."

Comment: @NagaVemprala - Hold on, you were able to push `master` before (i.e.when you pushed `40b66b1`) but now you do not have permissions? What changed?

Comment: I was removed the permission to push it on developer role. Got it back. Now I tried to PUSH . It worked. But for some reason we should not have commits on the master. How to delete the commits on master? The REVERT also created a new commit on master.

Comment: IF nobody has pulled since this all began, and IF those two commits are still the only two commits on master, then delete master on the server with `git push origin :master`. Then on your local machine do `git branch myfeature master~` so that `myfeature` now has your first commit, then delete master locally with `git branch -D master`.