# Git: How to perform hard push

Tags: git, git-push

I pushed a commit to the remote repository and I want to undo that commit.

To undo the commit in my local repository I used
`git reset --hard prev_commit_hash`
(By the way, is this the proper way to do that?)

Then I tried to push, and failed, because the tip of my current branch is behind its remote counterpart, as I expected.

The question is: What is the proper way to perform a hard/forced push?

Edit:
I viewed some of the other similar questions asked, but they were a little old.
The suggested solution was using `git revert`. And I saw that recently users commented that this solution is not working for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Undo pushed commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Comment: I'm not sure, it was published 2 years ago...

Comment: I'm not happy with the light finger down votes. I came across a problem and I'm asking a question here because it's a good community and I'm sure I'll find what I'm looking for. Besides, it's a good question and I'm sure many other users will find it very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Downvotes may be annoying, but if you keep showing effort in your questions, the number of upvotes will surpass the downvotes. Note a question being old does not mean it is good or bad. I for example posted few months ago an answer to that question. The goal of closing as duplicate is to keep the knowledge together, instead of having it spread out in different threads.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thank you for your comments

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using:

```
git push origin master -f
```

where `f` stands for *forced*.