# How to undo git push or move origin/mybranch to previous step?

Tags: git, undo

I have made wrong modifications in the code, then commited them, then pushed them to remote.

Now local `mybranch` and `origin/mybranch` are in sync.

The I found that my code if wrong. I would like to step back one comming. I did reset current branch to previous commit and got correct state in local repository, but unable to push this to remote.

If I do normal push, it merges and I stay on wrong code again.

After I did force push, I got my extra commits logically disappeared, but I still had the wrong code.

Now I am to revert my changes in old-fashion style manually.

Was it better way to perform?

Comment: Have you done `--soft` or `--hard` reset ?

Comment: @sajibkhan it won't work with already pushed stuff, will it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undoing a 'git push'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270514/undoing-a-git-push)

Comment: @Dims, no matter if you pushed or not. When we do force (-f) push `remote myBranch` history will be replaced with `local myBrance`.

Comment: @sajibkhan I haven't actually tried yet but he's saying that he forced the push with no results. I'd try a `git revert`

Comment: I think that main errors comes from the fact that you want to have the "perfect" branch from scratch. Do a first dev in a branch, then do another dev in a second branche etc... then do again another branch where you will make clean commit by doing cherry-pik. Then when it's really and tested (and maybe after a couple weeks) clean the extra branches. You might have your own remote push all intermediate branch to you remote in order not to pollute the common-dev remote-repo

Answer (score 0):

after reset to correct code

`git push origin mybranch -f`

-f means force

Answer (score 0):

You can revert the commit:

```
git revert <commit-hash>
```

Git will create a commit that undoes any changes in the commit provided

Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert

Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22683231/4499267

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to step back one comming[sic].

You should've

`git rebase -i origin/mybranch`

And select which commits you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete last commit with changes then need to do `--hard` reset.

```
$ git checkout mybranch
$ git reset --hard HEAD~1            # undo last commit with changes
$ git push -f origin HEAD
```