# Reverting the old commit that is made public and get it back to the main repository

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

How do we revert an old commit in git that has already been pushed and made public and get it back to the main repository?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Undo pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Comment: What does "get it back to the main repository" mean?

Comment: Like I wanted to know how to undo the commit i have done and roll back the original file.