# How to undo an initial push to a Git repository

Tags: git, repository

So, I started with an empty repository and wanted to copy an existing Git repository there. If I initially pushed the wrong existing repository to that new, empty repository, how would I go about reversing or undoing that initial push so I could push the proper existing repository to my new one?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits/31937298#31937298

Answer (score 1):

You can simply force push the correct existing repository to the remote one. Everything that is there will be overwritten:

```
git push -f
```

Comment: So, I did git push -f in the correct repository (and I made sure its origin was the remote repository I wanted to overwrite) and it said "everything up-to-date" but the remote repository was not overwritten, it still had the old repository in there. Do you know why?

Comment: So you run "git remote show origin" and both Fetch and Push URL point to the correct repository?

Comment: Yes, I've since figured it out though, but thank you so much!