# Using GitHub, how can I restore my local repository to the state it was in before my last push to the origin?

Tags: git, github

I did some work, committed this and pushed it to the origin. Now I realize I want to go back to the point before I did the work.

I would like to restore my local and my origin repository to this earlier commit to the origin and I don't need to keep any of the changes I just made either locally or on the origin.

I really want to be sure I don't make a mistake. How can I do this?  Do I need to first restore my local repo and then do another push to the origin?

Here's the command I think I need to do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

followed by a commit and push to the origin

But it's a bit risky for me so I would like to get some confirmation if I'm correct.

Comment: Are you working alone on that repo or do you share work on it with people?

Comment: I am working alone

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git - Undo pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume a recent history like this, where you'd want to return to commit C, since commits D and E are bad. I'll also assume this happens on master branch, but feel free to adapt.

```
A--B--C--D--E
            ^
          master <<< HEAD
```

---

How to locate which is the ref of the "good" commit to return to?

```
git log --oneline -15
```

should be enough to spot it (store its hash and use it in next command)

---

Now let's proceed on your local :

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard C
```

Then to reflect your new situation on the remote end (github)

```
git push --force origin HEAD
```

And the final situation will be

```
A--B--C                   D--E (dangling, will be garbage collected later)
      ^
    master <<< HEAD
```

Comment: Can you tell me, how can I know what the value of C is?

Comment: okay so I found out the hash is 4cdbec4    does that mean my command would be git reset --hard 4cdbec4  ?

Comment: okay so I found out the hash is 4cdbec4    does that mean my command would be git reset --hard 4cdbec4  ?

Comment: @Alan2 Yes, go for it.