# How to get a git branch to a previous commit and push it as the new HEAD?

Tags: git

Here is what happened. I have a master branch and a nv branch for my code.  The nv branch provides a variation of our applications gui requiered by special customers. However any changes in how the program works internally need to be appled to both branches.

Normally I do the changes to the master and then merge the changes to the nv branch. And push both branches.

I made a mistake and the last structural changes I made were to the nv branch. So when I decided to "correct " my mistake by switching over to master and merging I left both branches' gui looking like the nv branch.

This was all pushed. I m the sole developer. So all mistakes, again by me.

My questuon is how do I go back, in the master branch to how things were previous to my merge? And then I want to push it so that the current state of my master was as before the merge.

Thanks for any help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Comment: This could help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits/31937298#31937298