# Git - Reset origin/master

Tags: git

Someone messed up origin/master.  They merged about 15 commits into it that weren't supposed to go in until a future sprint.

I have what SHOULD be origin/master on a local branch.  How would I reset origin/master to be my local branch?

I'm thinking I could push my local branch, let's call it masterbackup, to the origin, then checkout origin/master, reset it to origin/masterbackup, then push.  So something like:

```
git push -u origin masterbackup
git checkout master
git pull
git reset --hard origin/masterbackup
git push
```

Will that work?

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git - Undo pushed commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is just one command:

(Read the entire answer before proceeding... I included optional "safety" commands at the end)

`git push -f origin masterbackup:master`

Here is the relevant part of the documentation describing the last parameter with the colon:

> <refspec>…​
>
> Specify what destination ref to update with what source
> object. The format of a  parameter is an optional plus +,
> followed by the source object , followed by a colon :, followed
> by the destination ref .
>
> The  is often the name of the branch you would want to push, but
> it can be any arbitrary "SHA-1 expression", such as master~4 or HEAD
> (see gitrevisions[7]).
>
> The  tells which ref on the remote side is updated with this
> push.

Source: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

In English, this command says: make the `master` branch in the `origin` repo point to the same commit as the `masterbackup` branch in the local repo.  In git terms, this is called "pushing `masterbackup` to `master` on remote `origin`"

If you want an extra level of safety, before you execute this command, do:

`git fetch origin master`

`git branch bad-master origin/master`

That way if you want to go back to the way it was before you fixed it, you can do:

`git push -f origin bad-master:master`

Once you are satisfied that you don't need to go back, you can delete that branch with:

`git branch -D bad-master`

The capital D is needed because otherwise git will refuse to delete a branch that will orphan commits.

As a final note... it seems that your roundabout method would also work, except that you would need a `-f` in the final `push` and it would also leave an unnecessary branch (`masterbackup`) on the remote.

(It seems you have the common misperception among git users that the remote repo is more important than it really is, perhaps as a side-effect of having used centralized vcs's.  This often expresses itself in unnecessary `push` and `pull` commands. A branch doesn't need to be "on the server" to be useful. The remote repo is *exactly* the same as your local repo... it has no extra powers.)