# git reset to previous commit and then push

Tags: git, git-revert

When trying to revert to a previous commit (for instance 123abc) via git reset

```
git reset --hard 123abc 
git commit -a -m "revert to 123abc"
```

I cannot push this (I need to pull before and pulling moves me forward).
I have come with this few lines:

```
for i in `git diff --name-only 123abc`; do git checkout 123abc $i; done
git commit -a -m "revert to 123abc"
```

Which works since now

```
 git diff --name-only 123abc
```

is empty

I was wondering if this is an hack or the git way to do it. In case it is not,
how to accomplish this correctly?

Comment: If you're resetting there's no need to commit again.

Comment: @evolutionxbox but I cannot push. I want origin to be aware of the fact that I want to reset.

Comment: By resetting you're changing the commit tree. The remote is likely refusing the push. You can force push, remove the remote branch and push again, or instead use revert instead of reset.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> When trying to revert ***to*** a previous commit (for instance 123abc) ...

The emphasis I added here on the preposition "to", as in ***revert to***, is crucial.  The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4114122/1256452) at your linked question ([How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/1256452)) calls this out:

> This depends a lot on what you mean by "revert".

Running `git revert` on *a single commit* may not suffice.  See the answers there about reverting multiple commits, if needed.

Running `git reset --hard` *may* suffice, but introduces the very problem you've encountered.  The things to understand here are:

1. A *branch name* simply lets Git *find* one particular commit.  We say that the branch name *points to* the commit.  Using `git reset`, we can change the one particular commit to which some branch name points.  **Nothing else happens in the repository yet**, although depending on the kind of `git reset` you run, something else might happen before `git reset` finishes: the first step of this `git reset` is just to change *one of your own branch names*.  Since you're considering (or have used) `--hard`, some more things will change in your repository, but they're less important at the moment.
2. *Every Git repository has its own branch names.*  Moving one of *your* branch names has no effect on any other repository.
3. What you need to do is to get *some other Git repository* to change one of *its* branch names.  That's where you run into this problem:

   > I cannot push this (I need to pull before and pulling moves me forward).

   The `git push` command is how you ask—or, using `--force`, command—some other Git repository to change or create or delete some of its names (branch names, tag names, and other such names).  But each Git repository is set up to *easily accept new incoming commits*, yet at the same time, *resist the suggestion to throw away any existing commits*.

When you use `git reset` to move one of your branch names "backwards", so as to ***revert to*** (not `revert` as in add-a-commit-that-backs-out) some previous commit, you're *deliberately throwing away some existing commit(s)*.  Since you control your own Git repository, you can definitely do this to your own repository.  Since the `git reset` command is *meant* to do this kind of throwing-away,<sup>1</sup> it does so without complaint.  But `git push` *isn't*, and *their* Git complains.

As soon as you use `git pull`, *their* repository has you *put back* all the commits you snipped out of your own repository.  Git is, after all, designed to *add* commits as easily as possible!  That leaves you with the situation you're in.

You now have a choice:

- **Force** the other Git repository to discard some commits.  This requires sufficient permissions.  It also means that *everyone else who is using that other Git repository* need to take action with any clones *they* have made, because *their* clones will enthusiastically put back all the commits you are attempting to prune.  So this is kind of mean to those other people.
- Or, use `git revert` or some other command to *add some commit(s)* to your repository that, in the end, result in putting the *files back*, but don't *remove* any *old* commits.  The new commits simply *add on* to the old ones.  The old ones are still there for anyone who would like to ask about them (`git log`) or use them (`git switch --detach hash-id`, for instance).

Adding new commit(s) is what Git is designed to do, so the latter is the way to go unless there's some really strong reason to ditch the old commits.

As the question you linked notes, all of this is a lot easier with *unpublished* commits: a commit that *only you have*, in your own private repository, is simply *not in* any other Git repository.  If you shave those commits off your own branches, nobody will ever know.  They won't be *able* to object that a `git push` shaves those commits off their branches, because those commits aren't *on* their branches.  (Again, each *branch name* is local to each Git repository.  One repository can show another one the commit hash ID stored in its branch name, but each repository takes responsibility in keeping its own hash IDs in its own branch names.  The *commits* get shared; the *branch names* do not.)

Since the commits you're looking at are *published* you cannot use this short-cut.

---

<sup>1</sup>This makes `git reset` a very-high-powered tool, like some sort of flame-throwing chainsaw, or industrial steel-cutting laser, or something.  This over-powered-ness is part of the reason that Git 2.23 now has `git restore`: some of the things you can do, that used to require using `git reset`, can now be done with the rather gentler `git restore`.  Both commands *will throw away in-progress work* if you ask them, but `git restore` is more like a hand-saw, or bolt cutters, or something along these lines.

Comment: This is a very nice and detailed explanation. I especially like the comparison of git reset to a flame-throwing chainsaw or industrial steel-cutting laser However, you did not say the command to force a git push to delete commits on origin. Is it git push --force?

Comment: @EthanGroat: yes, `git push --force` (which is the raw brute force without any double checking method), or `git push --force-with-lease` (which lets you insert double checking along the way), or the newfangled `--force-if-includes` (similar to `--force-with-lease`, introduced in case of background fetch updates with the new `git maintenance` suite).

Comment: @torek What are the actions that the user users of the repo have to do after I `reset --hard` and `push --force`?

Comment: @steffen: they must check *their* Git repositories. You told some third-party repository (e.g., on GitHub) "discard a bunch of commits, because I don't like them." Those other users might *have* those commits. Their Git software will now think that those commits are new, made by them, and should be *added to* the GitHub repository. If that's wrong, *they* must take action in *their* repositories to make sure it does not happen. What actions they should take depends on what they want to do with those commits (do they want to keep them somewhere, or throw them away?).

Comment: Git is built to *add* commits, not remove them. Therefore, whenever you remove some commits, you must make sure that nobody else who has them already will re-add them. Git software everywhere will gladly re-take the discarded commits, because "add commits" is a natural thing for a Git repository. "Remove commits" is the one that requires force.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using `git revert <commit hash>`. This will revert the selected commit and you can then push the changes

Comment: I cannot push: I'm told I'm behind and I have to pull before pushing. This puts me away from the commit I want to push

Comment: Have you tried doing git pull and then doing the git revert i described above

Comment: Yes of course, I enter in an infinite loop: revert, pull, revert, pull,... The point is I cannot push after the revert backward and, once pulled, i am moved to the tip of the branch.

Comment: Maybe trying doing git pull and then `git reset --hard <commit hash>`

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

It is a hack. Use

`git revert <commit hash>`

but beware, you are reverting the changes applied by the `<commit hash>`, so to revert to previous commit, use

`git revert HEAD`

This will create another commit that is reverting a change caused by the last commit. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22683231/12118546

This above is a proper way how to do this with putting the reverting itself to the history also. If you are the only one working in the repo, you can also force push the branch with the latest commit removed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31937298/12118546

Comment: What is a hack?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: Hack = Abusing a system in unintended way to achieve your goals.

Comment: Sorry, I understand what the word means. I wanted to know what you consider to be a hack in the question above. Nothing is being used in an unintended way.

Comment: Well, the OP created his way of doing `git revert`. Linguistics isn't exact science, but I would consider this to be a hacky way of reverting a commit...

Comment: Resetting is a valid approach. It’s that the OP didn’t know how to finish the task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit