# How can I delete a previos commit file on github or hide it? Accidentally exposed a private key

Tags: git, github, google-api, git-commit, private-key

I accidentally exposed a private key in one of my files when I pushed it to github. Thankfully I got a warning email from google about my api being exposed.
After I updated the file and pushed the commit, i have been unable to delete my previous commits.

Is it possible to delete previous commits on github or do I have to delete my repositoy and start all over again?[image]

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/git-undo-pushed-commits/36177806 will solve your issue

Comment: This is a FAQ on GitHub: https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository