# how to remove unmerged commit

Tags: git, commit

how can i remove a unmerged but pushed commit .
i have 2 commits in   one pull request 1 is unintentional  i want to remove it how can i do that ?
I delted all files in my local folder which is conected to remote  (i though it will only reflect in my local repo because i am not pushing it and  i thought i deleted them after remote remove origin)i dont know this is hapening till i made a push request next day so curently i am haveing 2 commits in one pull request and if i merge  files will be deleted from my repo ? at this point what should i do if this hapends again? i messed up more after this i did so many things from online witout know what they actualy do and messed it up even more now to check my curent state i made 1 more pr now i have 4 commits in 1 pr from which only one should be merged i closed it without merge last time and now also did it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I undo pushed commits using git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682870/how-can-i-undo-pushed-commits-using-git)