# Cleaning the git repository

Tags: git

I have a new git repository in which I made 1 commit and made a push. I forgot to set up a git ignore and now a lot of garbage got into it. Now I set up a git ignore, but now how to remove all the garbage from the repository?

Comment: What prevents you from removing the files?

Comment: Manually delete every file from the repository?

Comment: Use `git filter-branch` to remove these file from history, or simply delete them and make a commit (remains in history but not tracked in the future).

Comment: Try some of the solutions outlined in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore

Comment: You might want to revert the inital commit, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632191/how-to-revert-initial-git-commit), and commit again, this time with `.gitignore` in place.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case (repo init), just revert your last commit and then include an adapted .gitignore.

To revert your last commit and keep files staged :

```
  git reset --soft HEAD^1
```