# Git - how can I go back to initial commit?

Tags: git

I have a git repo with only one commit. In my local master branch, I have accidentally made a
`git commit --amend` so now I get a message saying

```
On branch master 

Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
```

How can I discard the amended commit and go back to the original commit? I want to have my local master and origin/master up to date with nothing to commit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to revert initial git commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6632191/how-to-revert-initial-git-commit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [reflog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) to reset `master` to the commit it referenced *before* the current one:

```
git reset --hard master@{1}
```

The reflog is a real life saver in situations like these. It's well worth reading up on it in the [Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Maintenance-and-Data-Recovery/#_data_recovery):

> At some point in your Git journey, you may accidentally lose a commit. Generally, this happens because you force-delete a branch that had work on it, and it turns out you wanted the branch after all; or you hard-reset a branch, thus abandoning commits that you wanted something from. Assuming this happens, how can you get your commits back? [...]
>
> Often, the quickest way is to use a tool called `git reflog`.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset your current `master` branch to be the same as the origin one with:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Note that this will remove any changes on your current `master` branch that are not in `origin/master`.

Comment: While this will likely do the job in OP's case, I wouldn't recommend it as a general way to "undo" your local commits, since you may end up with new commits from the remote branch that you might not be interested in quite yet.

Answer (score 1):

Since, you are on 'origin/master' and wants to reset use below git reset comand.

`git reset --hard origin/master`

**Explanation:**
From [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

`git-reset` - Reset current HEAD to the specified state

`--hard` - it is the mode option (optional). hard Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since  are discarded.