# Creating git submodule to replaced copied and modified files

Tags: git

I have a git project which contains some files copied from another git project. Now I want to convert those files into a git submodule. Can I do that without losing the history of the changes I already did?
thanks!

Comment: You should instead, first add the second repo as a submodule, then you make your own commits on the submodule which can include deleting files

Comment: I believe the answer to your question is already covered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of your repository, eliminate everything outside future submodule using `git filter-branch`. So you have only commits describing what happened in that subdirectory and directory hiearchy looks exactly same as in future submodule.

Then add this new repository as a remote to upstream repository and do a merge. Git will say something about no common ancestor, but it should work.

After all this delete the subdirectory in your project and put submodule on it's place (in one commit).