# How do I cut a git repository in two?

Tags: git

I have a git repository which has several commits into different sub-directories and I want to cut the repository in two in the following way:

```
/
  sub1/
  sub2/
  sub3/
```

`->`

```
/
  sub1/
```

The individual subs have evolved to a point where `sub1` should be an independent repository. Also there isn't a single commit that touches more than one sub.

So, I'd like to somehow extract a new repository that only takes commits made into `sub1` while leaving all other stuff out. But I want to keep the history (but not have the commits related to `sub2` nor `sub3`).

<sub>Note: I vaguely remember there to be some command to do this, but I never used it myself and don't remember what it was called, so I cannot search for it.</sub>

Comment: Additional duplicate: [Split large Git repository into many smaller ones](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3910412/430766).