# extract multiple directories using git-filter-branch

Tags: git, git-svn, git-rebase, git-filter-branch

I have a big repository which currently contains multiple projects in top level subfolders, say `/a`, `/b`, `/c`, and `/d`.

Now I want to split up that repository into two different repositories: one containing `/a` and `/b` and the other containing `/c` and `/d`.

I am aware of `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter`, which is perfect for extracting a single directory, but it seems not to be able to extract multiple directories at once.

I am also aware of `git filter-branch --prune-empty --tree-filter`, which would allow me to delete everything, but the two wanted directories. This feels not completely right, as I have to manually specify all toplevel directories that might exist.

Is there a better way to extract two directories out of a big repository?

PS: Of course any good solution using something other than `git filter-branch` is fine. ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detach many subdirectories into a new, separate Git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982055/detach-many-subdirectories-into-a-new-separate-git-repository)

Comment: The `git filter-repo` answer should be accepted now, as it's way easier to use and safer than `git filter-branch`

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter 'bash preserve-only.sh a b' -- --all
```

where `preserve-only.sh` is:

```
IFS=':'
GLOBIGNORE="$*"
rm -rf *
```

This should remove everything but `a` and `b` from all commits of all branches, which should be the same as extracting exactly the given directories.

To complete the actual split you can use a filter like `rm -rf a b` to get all the changes not extracted in the first run.

---

Update: While trying to speed things up using `--index-filter` I came to an even easier solution:

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --index-filter \
  'git rm --cached -r -q -- . ; git reset -q $GIT_COMMIT -- a b' -- --all
```

This just removes everything and afterwards restores the given directories afterwards.

Comment: The index-filter option is, by far, the best. One suggestions: add `--ignore-unmatch` to the `git rm` statement to suppress an error where `.` doesn't match anything (empty repo after a commit).

Comment: Awesome, just what was I was looking for. Worked on nested directories as well. Thanks!

Comment: for the tags, I added `--tag-name-filter cat`

Comment: what is `$GIT_COMMIT` ?

Comment: This worked like a charm for me. I thought `$GIT_COMMIT` is an environment variable defined earlier, but it seems to be something git-internal. I do get three lines of warning though: `WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged` / `WARNING: You said to rewrite tagged commits, but not the corresponding tag.` / `WARNING: Perhaps use '--tag-name-filter cat' to rewrite the tag.`, so it seems a good move to add `--tag-name-filter cat` as stated in earlier comments.

Comment: Probably the second option using `index-filter` should be emphasized much more. Having a short attention span, I simply started with the first command and stopped reading. This would have taken hours to complete for our big repo. Fortunately I came back to this thread to discover the 'Update' and this worked within just seconds.

Comment: This answer is obsolete, now prefer the `git filter-repo` way, see answer from @Cem.S below!!

Answer (score 8):

After searching around and trying the proposed solutions, it seems like the recommended way of doing is now with `git-filter-repo` (see [here](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/#simple-example-with-comparisons))

```
git filter-repo --path a --path b
```

Comment: Currently there are some problems with installing it on Windows, but after it's installed, it works nicely and simply

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any better way than `tree-filter` for this.  So you already have all the information you need.  Now just do it!

Start by creating your two branches:

```
git branch br1
git branch br2
```

Now for each branch, check it out, then filter it using the `tree-filter`.

You could then split them out to separate directories either by pushing them out, or by cloning or pulling them in.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this

```
git filter-branch -f --prune-empty --tree-filter "ls -I a -I b | xargs rm -rf"  -- --all
```