# How can I move multiple directories in a Git?

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

There is a Git repository like this.

```
   repo/
      A1/
        B1/
          C1/
      A2/
        B2/
          C2/
```

I would like to have one like this.

```
   repo/
      C1/
      C2/
```

I don't need A1, B1, A2, B2 directories any more.

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv A1/B1/C1 .' HEAD
Rewrite xxxx(1/206)mv: cannot stat 'A1/B1/C1': No such file or directory
tree filter failed: mv A1/B1/C1 .
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I do not want to use git move. I would like to use files under C1 and C2 as if they were under repo/C1 and repo/C2 from the beginning.

Comment: Do you want to delete the directories A1, B1, A2 and B2

Comment: Yes, I would like to delete A1, B1, A2 and B2 as if they were not there from the beginning.
I checked this, but could not work.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142419/how-can-i-move-a-directory-in-a-git-repo-for-all-commits

Comment: If there is only one directory I can do like this.
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter
Unfortunately. --subdirectory-filter supports only one directory.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954485/extract-multiple-directories-using-git-filter-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv A1/B1/C1 .' HEAD
```

This code ends up with error like

> "mv: cannot stat 'A1/B1/C1': No such file or directory".

But this code below worked correctly.

```
$ git filter-branch --tree-filter "ls A1/B1 | xargs -i -t mv A1/B1/{} A1 | sh" HEAD
```

I do not know why the first code does not work, but it seems ok.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter-branch` command iterates through the whole history of your repo. You may get the `No such file or directory` error if the folder hasn't been existed from the beginning, and as `mv` returns with nonzero exit code, the whole iteration stops.

The simplest solution is to append `|| true` to the filter command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'mv A1/B1/C1 . || true' HEAD
```

You will still receive the `No such file or directory` messages for the steps when the folder was nonexistent but at least the process will not stop immediately.

Answer (score -1):

just move them in terminal or file manager and commit changes.

Comment: I need previous history. I would like to use C1 and C2 as if they were under repo from the begging.

Comment: your previous history is saved in git. for example i have website coded in just html, recently deleted everything and made it as wordpress site, I can go back to html files with checkout any time I want. that is how version control works, you can delete, move files how you want, they will be in your history no matter what.

Comment: I am pretty familiar with VCS.

old: repo/A1/B1/C1/ddd.txt
new: repo/C1/ddd.txt
   I would like to get a new repository as if ddd.txt was repo/C1/ddd.txt from the beginning.