# How do I `git filter-branch` multiple subdirectories and keep their parent directories?

Tags: git

Suppose I have a repository with a folder structure something like this:

```
|-dir1
|-dir2
| |-subdir1
| |-subdir2
| |-subdir3
|-dir3
```

I was hoping I could simply `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` my way out of it, but I seem to encounter two challenges:

- It seems I cannot supply multiple `--subdirectory-filter` arguments? At least it does not seem to include all the subdirectories I wanted.
- git seems to strip off the parent directories.

So what do I do if I want to filter my repo to get this result?:

```
|-dir1
|-dir2
| |-subdir1
| |-subdir3
```

*Addition:*

As suggested in the comments, I have tried:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf dir2/subdir2' --prune-empty
```

but this was quite slow, so I got impatient with it. `git help filter-branch` seemed to suggest that I could use `--index-filter` instead of `--tree-filter` to make it faster, so I was hoping I could simply do this instead:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -rf dir2/subdir2' --prune-empty
```

However, even though it seems to be working through my commits and doing something it ends with the message:

> WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged

and 'dir2/subdir' and its contents is still in my working copy. So I clearly misunderstood something. I am curious what the right way to do it with `--index-filter` might be?

Comment: I think you need `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf dir2/subdir2 dir3/'`. Plus `-f` if necessary.

Comment: @ElpieKay I'll give it a try

Comment: @ElpieKay `--tree-filter` takes forever, so I tried `--index-filter` instead as various sources seem to suggest that this should have the same effect. However, even though it gets very busy re-writing commits, it does not have any effect in my actual working copy and also ends with the message **WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged**. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry but I haven’t encountered your problem. Does your repo have a large number of files and commits?

Comment: You could edit your proposed `--index-filter` into the question. I'll note here in this comment that the commands in a tree filter are simple (but slow); the corresponding commands to go in an index filter tend to be a lot harder to write.

Comment: @torek I elaborated a bit on my approach now. I hope someone can help me figure out what I did wrong.

Answer (score 4):

This is in fact the problem:

> ```
> git filter-branch --index-filter 'rm -rf dir2/subdir2' --prune-empty
> ```

An *index filter* must operate on Git's *index* (also called the *staging area* or the *cache*, depending on which particular Git documentation you are looking at).

Fortunately, for this particular case there's a Git command that is equivalent to `rm -rf`, that operates (only) on Git's index:

```
git rm --cached -rf --ignore-unmatch dir2/subdir2
```

We need the `--cached` part to make it work only on the index, the `-r` to make it behave like `rm -r`, and the `-f --ignore-unmatch` to make it behave like `rm -f`.  Hence the full filter-branch command is at least:

```
git filter-branch \
    --index-filter 'git rm --cached -rf --ignore-unmatch dir2/subdir2' \
    --prune-empty
```

(You may want to add `--tag-name-filter cat` and/or other filter-branch options.)

(The filter-branch command is full of little quirks because it has to copy *every* commit it "filters", and this is very slow.  The `--tree-filter` is the simplest to use because it works with all the normal file system operations, but that makes it the slowest, as well.)

Comment: Is there a way to re-write this command so instead of listing files/directories that I want to delete in `--ignore-unmatch` we would list the ones we want to keep?

Comment: @Roberto: no, but a *diffrerent* `--index-filter` can do that. It's not entirely trivial to write, but someone already wrote one. I just don't know which StackOverflow answer has it in it...

Comment: found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954485/extract-multiple-directories-using-git-filter-branch  - although removing everything and then reseting, for each commit, sounds SUPER slow. What do you think?

Comment: Remove-and-reset of index isn't all that slow. (It *is* very slow as a *tree* filter.) There's another method using `git update-index` and `sed` that I've seen as well, but the accepted answer, with its speedup to use the index filter, should be fine.