# How do you split a git repo, mainaining only the history per directory?

Tags: git

Say I have a git repository with the structure:

```
my-repo/
  .git/
  directory-one/
    [...]
  directory-two/
    [...]
```

I need to split the repo into two repositories (one for `directory-one` and the other for `directory-two`). I'd like to maintain the history of each of those subdirectories, but **no code from `directory-one` can appear in the history of `directory-two`**, and vice versa.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: You lose any non-merged, non-master branches with this process.

1. `cp -R my-repo/ my-repo-one/`
2. `cd my-repo-one/`
3. `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf directory-two" HEAD`
4. `mv .git directory-one/`
5. `git checkout -f`
6. `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directory-one`

This gets you a repo with only the history from `directory-one/`. Repeat the process for `directory-two/`.

Thanks to [minitech](https://stackoverflow.com/users/707111/minitech) for steps 4-6!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `git filter-branch` with `--subdirectory-filter`, which was built exactly for this:

```
# Clear the two directories entirely
rm -rf directory-one/ directory-two/
mkdir directory-one/ directory-two/

# Add the original .git to each one
cp -R .git directory-one/
mv .git directory-two/

# Check out the repo into the empty directory and filter it to that directory
cd directory-one/
git checkout -f
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directory-one/

# Repeat
cd ../directory-two/
git checkout -f
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter directory-two/
```

**Make a backup first.**

Comment: The problem with that method is that there is still code from `directory-one/` in the diffs of the repo that was created at `directory-two/`. For data security reasons, no code that was ever in `directory-one/` is allowed to be visible in `directory-two/`'s history.

Comment: @Kerrick: There shouldn’t be… how do they appear?

Comment: In commits that touched both directories, I can see diffs that include code from the other directory.

Comment: @Kerrick: What filename does the other directory appear as? You could try using that with `--index-filter`…

Comment: I figured it out! Your answer is step 2. Step 1 is `git filter-branch --tree-filter "rm -rf directory-one" HEAD`. This leaves you with a repo that only has `directory-two/`'s history, and all the files that were directly inside `directory-one/` are now at the repo root.