# Split a git repo clean into two git repos

Tags: git, github

I want to split my git repo into two seperate gits.

I have two seperate folders in my repo. I want to move the one to a new, a clean repo. The other one will stay unchanged in the current repo. Also I want to copy all branches and commits but without the changes done at the other folder.

Clearly I want to seperate one team into two. The two teams shouldn't have access to the other's folder and also no history regarding repo commits.

I'm not quite sure if this is possible because of the repo history.

Although, thanks for your help!

Comment: There is no such thing as "a git". Git is a version control system. Are you talking about splitting apart a repository?

Comment: Course I mean my repo...

Comment: Then you should say "my repo", not "my git", which at best is ambiguous and at worst makes no sense.

Comment: Although, why is this a duplicate? I didn't found something on the internet.

Comment: This question is already asked and answered at the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910412/split-large-git-repository-into-many-smaller-ones