# How do I reword the very first git commit message?

Tags: git, message, git-rebase, git-commit, revision-history

### I have a working tree containing 3 commmits:

➜  ~myproject git:(master) `git log`

```
commit a99cce8240495de29254b5df8745e41815db5a75
Author: My Name <my@mail.com>
Date:   Thu Aug 16 00:59:05 2012 +0200

    .gitignore edits

commit 5bccda674c7ca51e849741290530a0d48efd69e8
Author: My Name <my@mail.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 13 01:36:39 2012 +0200

    Create .gitignore file

commit 6707a66191c84ec6fbf148f8f1c3e8ac83453ae3
Author: My Name <my@mail.com>
Date:   Mon Aug 13 01:13:05 2012 +0200

    Initial commit (with a misleading message)
```

### Now I wish to [`reword`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) the commit message of my *first commit* (6707a66)

➜  ~myproject git:(master) `git rebase -i 6707`

(…entering vim)

```
pick 5bccda6 Create .gitignore file
pick a99cce8 .gitignore edits

# Rebase 6707a66..a99cce8 onto 6707a66
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

In this case, I wish to correct (`reword` in git parlance) the commit message in question:

> Initial commit (with a misleading message)

…to something appropriate.

Unsurprisingly, my attempt above didn't succeed since the first commit obviously doesn't have any *parent* commit. (And when you `rebase`, you need to reference the next oldest commit *prior* to the one you wish to `reword`, right?)

The gist of my question, thus, can you achieve this by any other means of doing it?

Comment: Or you could just leave it for all time as a repository [tawdry quirk.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1A4JfCmu5oc#t=0m50s)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the message of the first commit? (git)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/changing-the-message-of-the-first-commit-git)

Comment: ^ Very true... I thought I had searched properly for this particular question but that's the same one as mine. There goes a huge amount of perfecting my question's copywriting. :-P

Comment: @hced: :) your copywriting doesn't go to waste - it'll help other people to find a solution in the future, even it it were to get closed as a duplicate

Comment: Anyone who comes across this question may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17643063/456814) to [Changing the message of the first commit? (git)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/changing-the-message-of-the-first-commit-git) to be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change first commit of project with Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 298, accepted):

Do `git rebase -i --root`

(point to `root` instead of pointing to a specific commit)

This way, the first commit is also included and you can just `reword` it like any other commit.

The `--root` option was introduced in Git `v1.7.12` (2012). Before then the only option was to use `filter-branch` or `--amend`, which is typically harder to do.

Note: see also [this similar question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14630424/1075152).

Answer (score 12):

[pcreux's gist](https://gist.github.com/1681580) has a good way to reword the first commit:

```
# You can't use rebase -i here since it takes the parent commit as argument.
# You can do the following though:
git checkout FIRST_COMMIT_SHA && git commit --amend && git rebase HEAD master
```

Comment: As of [git 1.7.12](https://raw.github.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.12.txt), `git rebase -i --root` is the way to go, as suggested by florisla.

Answer (score 11):

You can always use `git filter-branch --msg-filter`:

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter \
  'test $GIT_COMMIT = '$(git rev-list --reverse master |head -n1)' &&
echo "Nice message" || cat' master
```

Comment: fork0: That's great, thanks. Curious, is this to be considered "legitimate" practice, for lack of better word. I mean, is it common/recommended to do it like this? Also, can you do this time and time again in cases with faulty commit messages? Reason for asking that is because I first did it with the wrong commit SHA-1, copying your snippet (yours was the latest commit whereas I wanted to change the very first one). After using the command once again, this time with correct SHA-1 (first commit; 6707a66), it barfed on me.

Comment: Well, it is common :) And yes, you can repeat it. If you just add `-f` it will go ahead and always rewrite the commits of the given branch. The branch reference value from the first time was saved in `refs/original/master`, before you ran the command.

Comment: Of course, you can just remove (or rename) the saved reference.

Comment: I updated the code to make sure the mistake with copied commit id does not happen. Now the code is even copy-pastable. **A word of warning**, though: it does not work correctly if there are more than one initial commit (i.e. when you merged two or more unrelated branches)

Comment: @hced: You should be aware that rewriting any commit that's considered to be "published history" is usually a bad idea.  In your case, that would mean that you generally shouldn't do this if anyone else would ever have been working on a commit that had your root commit as an ancestor.