# What does the single circumflex in the windows cmd shell mean: More?

Tags: windows, cmd

This might not be really a question related to programming, but I have wondered for a long time, what the following cmd command means....:

[image: ^]

Just type a single circumflex in the cmd shell and windows will ask for more... And as long as you enter an even number of circumflexes, windows can't get enough. I have wondered since Vista... is this just some sort of "easter egg" or is there a purpose behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears appending `^` just lets you continue to write a command in the next line:

```
C:\Users\Felk>echo ^
More? hello ^
More? world
hello world
```

Turns out `^` is just the escape character for the windows shell.

```
C:\Users\Felk>echo |
Syntaxerror.

C:\Users\Felk>echo ^|
|
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20342828/3688648)

Comment: this seems to be true, i would have never thought of that... I'll accept this as answer tomorrow, if nobody has a better explanation :p

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Dank dir für deine Hilfe ;)

Comment: Kein Ding, hab selber was gelernt!

Comment: Circumflex is an escape character according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342902/521554