# ^ Character in Node Script Arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, special-characters

I have a node script that is receiving the following argument: `^PPP`.

I am calling the script as following: `npm run scriptName ^PPP`.

However inside the script if I do a `console.log(process.argv)`, the output shows my argument as `PPP`.

I tried escaping the character as `npm run scriptName \^PPP` and `npm run scriptName "^PPP"` but to no avail.

Please help how can I receive the original string from the arguments.

PowerShell to run command and v10.16.2 node version

Comment: Not sure if this helps but double quotes has different meaning in bash. Try `npm run scriptName '^PPP'`

Comment: What command line system are you using(windows,linux, etc)? ^ is an escape character in windows command so you may need to double escape it, eg `^^ppp` if that is what you are using

Comment: Thank you for you input Rajesh, but that still did not work

Comment: as @Rajesh comment. It will surely works. And here is example :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351521/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-a-node-js-program

Comment: My node version is ```v10.16.2```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your terminal.

I made a simple script called args.js with

```
console.log(process.argv);
```

---

Using git bash on windows or WSL (Ubuntu), calling

```
$node args.js ^PPPP
```

Outputs

> [ 'node/path',
>     'path/to/args.js',
>     '^PPPP' ]

---

Using windows cmd terminal, calling

```
>node args.js ^PPPP
```

Outputs

> [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>     'C:\workspace\tests\args.js',
>     'PPPP' ]

and calling

```
>node args.js ^^PPPP
```

Outputs

> [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>     'C:\workspace\tests\args.js',
>     '^PPPP' ]

---

So if you are using Windows's terminal, you need to double the `^` character ([What does the single circumflex in the windows cmd shell mean: More?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33946226/what-does-the-single-circumflex-in-the-windows-cmd-shell-mean-more)). On other terminals, it seems to work fine.

---

**Edit:** To add arguments to your node script from [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script), you need to separate them with `--` like so:

```
>npm run scriptName -- ^^PPP
```

Comment: Although I have just tested this and this is correct. This is only happening if I call the script directly by ```node scriptName ^^PPP``` but I am trying to run a script defined in the ```package.json```. So want I want to do (that is failing) is ```npm run scriptName ^^PPP``` and the latter is still not working.

Comment: To add arguments to your node script from `npm run`, you need to separate them with `--` like so : `npm run scriptName -- ^^PPP`