# How to echo a redirect command to a txt

Tags: batch-file, redirect, vbscript, cmd, echo

I'm trying to create a batch script which will create another batch script.
The problem is that one of the lines doesn't add and instead redirects to another file when it encounters the redirect that I want to create.

```
@echo off
:: Pulls name variable from text file
set /p UN=<name.txt
::Begins creating sec.bat
echo @echo off >sec.bat
:: Creates a vbs script to say whatever the %UN% variable is previously set as to the user
echo echo set speech = wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >>temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo set text=%UN%! >>sec.bat
:: This is where my error is happening. I want it to write the entire line
:: "echo speech.speak "%text%" >> temp.vbs" to sec.bat but it won't. It
:: instead writes the line in a file called temp.vbs
echo echo speech.speak "%text%" >> temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo start temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo timeout /t 1 >>nul >>sec.bat
echo del temp.vbs >>sec.bat
```

I've tried putting the lines individually in quotations but that causes it to write the quotations to the bat file as well and it does not work as intended.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what does symbol ^ means in Batch script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342828/what-does-symbol-means-in-batch-script) or any other question and answer found with [\[batch-file\] redirect echo create](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+redirect+echo+create)

Answer (score 0):

Escaping `>>` (`^>^>`) should be enough:

```
@echo off
set /p UN=<name.txt
echo @echo off >sec.bat
echo echo set speech = wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") ^>^>temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo set text=%UN%! >>sec.bat
echo echo speech.speak "%text%" ^>^> temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo start temp.vbs >>sec.bat
echo timeout /t 1 ^>^>nul >>sec.bat
echo del temp.vbs >>sec.bat
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have a different issue now, it's printing the redirects properly but it's not adding the variable %text%. The output in sec.bat looks like this:

@echo off 
echo set speech = wscript.CreateObject("SAPI.spVoice") >>temp.vbs 
set text=Username! 
echo speech.speak "" >>temp.vbs 
start temp.vbs 
timeout /t 1 >nul 
del temp.vbs 

I'm guessing it's because the first bat that is creating this tries to print the variable %test% but since it hasn't been set it prints nothing. I tried using the ^ escape but it didn't seem to work. just made the line: ..."speak "^" "

Comment: Nevermind just found out I can do this by using double %. =D Ty for the help.