# Inconsistent behavior npm

Tags: node.js, npm, semantic-versioning

I'm using `npm install` with advanced range, e.g. `npm i karma@^1.0.0` and  for Linux and OSX I get the latest version of package, but for windows platform, npm ignores range (caret symbol) and installs v.1.0.0

According to [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install), I have to enclose version range with quotes.
So, this `npm i karma@"^1.0.0"` works on windows properly.

> Note that most version ranges must be put in quotes so that your shell will treat it as a single argument.

But why does it affect only windows? What might be the cause of this inconsistency?

npm - v.4.0.5

node - v.7.4.0

Thanks.

Comment: It's a different *shell*, I don't think npm deals with the arguments it receives any differently. Write a simple program that prints out the arguments it receives if you want to investigate how your shell is parsing the command.

Comment: it also occurs if I spawn `npm install` command, does it also related to shell?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I've investigated `process.argv` array after installation with range and for this command `npm i carma@^1.0.0` argument's array look like: `[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
  'i',
 'karma@1.0.0' ]` (caret symbol is removed) and for this command `npm i carma@~1.0.0` it looks like `[ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
  'i',
  'karma@~1.0.0' ]` (tilda symbol persists). How is it possible?

Comment: Evidently your shell isn't including the caret, which is why you need to put it in quotes. Looks like it's a special character in cmd.exe: http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/q-what-cmdexe-line-continuation-character

Comment: Yep, I guess windows shell is processing caret as special symbol (for line continuations or for escaping reserved shell characters like & | ( < > ^ according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342828/what-does-symbol-means-in-batch-script).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143605/discussion-between-bob-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: So it seems you should be able to provide your own answer here.  The caret is a special symbol in Windows cmd.exe.  See also [quoting and escaping](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping).