# Char loss in argument string when call excutables with system in C++

Tags: c++, windows

I use `system` to call an external excutable file with argument list.

```
string all = (excuteablePath + " " + inputDir + " " + outputDir + " " + spacing);
system(all.c_str());
```

The value of string `all` shown in IDE or with `cout` is

`.\sample.exe .\孙夏^4735\UR7\ .\孙夏^4735\UR7.stl 0.3 0.3 0.3`

but the output from the executable is

`.\sample.exe .\孙夏4735\UR7\ .\孙夏4735\UR7.stl 0.3 0.3 0.3`

The character `^` disappered.

Why is this happened and how may I solve this?

Comment: This may be related to the fact that `^` is a special escape character for the Windows console. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342828/what-does-symbol-means-in-batch-script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use wide string characters and [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
std::wstring wstr =
    L".\\sample.exe .\\孙夏^4735\\UR7\\ .\\孙夏^4735\\UR7.stl 0.3 0.3 0.3";
STARTUPINFOW si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcessW(0, &wstr[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Note the `W` after `STARTUPINFO` and `CreateProcess`

If you are forced to use ANSI code page then use the ANSI version of `CreateProcess`

```
std::string str =
    ".\\sample.exe .\\孙夏^4735\\UR7\\ .\\孙夏^4735\\UR7.stl 0.3 0.3 0.3";
STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcessA(0, &str[0], NULL, NULL, TRUE, NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
```

Comment: Yes this exactly fix my problem, thank you. But I finally decided to remove all `^` in my string.