# Batch - Meaning of escaped vertical bar | before equal sign =

Tags: batch-file, scripting, windows-scripting, scripting-language

I am currently struggling understanding a line of an [introduction to windows batch scripting](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html):

```
SET /A errno=0
SET /A ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND=2

... 
... SET /A errno^|=%ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND%
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342902/5233188) answer the circumflex `^` is an escape character, so we are ending up with `errno|=%ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND%`. But then what is this code doing?

In the according article the author states that this gives *the flexibility to bitwise OR multiple error numbers together*.

Ok, but I couldn't find any article about bitwise operations in batch with a line like above...

So please, enlight me a little.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the paragraph above the code in question states, this is a `bitwise OR` operator. It is used to set multiple binary flags simultaneously.

In the code

```
SET /A ERROR_HELP_SCREEN=1
SET /A ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND=2
SET /A ERROR_OTHERCOMMAND_FAILED=4
```

ERROR_HELP_SCREEN is 0b001
ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND is 0b010
ERROR_OTHERCOMMAND_FAILED is 0b100

Using a bitwise OR will allow you to return something like 0b101, which would mean that an other command failed and a help screen error was raised.

The `^` is necessary because batch scripts treat `|` like pipes regardless of context, so `SET /A errno|=%ERROR_OTHERCOMMAND_FAILED%` will throw a syntax error even though it's perfectly valid on the command line.

Comment: Just to add to this: when quoting the `set /A "var=value"` pair you don't need to escape and with `set /A` you don't need to include the percent signs for variable names `SET /A "errno|=ERROR_SOMECOMMAND_NOT_FOUND"`