# Are there exceptions to the command line arguments passed to the main function?

Tags: c++, cmd

I am playing with command line arguments and implementing a very basic calculator which takes input before execution rather than at runtime. It works for 4 operations, but I am stuck at the power operation and after hours identified the fault. Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    stringstream s(strcat(strcat(argv[1], " "), argv[3]));
    int a, b;
    s >> a >> b;

    switch(argv[2][0]) {
        case '+':
            cout << a+b;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << a-b;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << a*b;
            break;
        case '/':
            cout << a/b;
            break;
        case 'p':
            cout << pow(a, b);
            break;
        default:
            cerr << "Invalid operation";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

The problem here is that earlier, I used '^' instead of 'p'. This character doesn't work at all, i.e., nothing is printed to console. I used debug prints, modified header files, typecasted a and b to double in pow() but the bug was this nasty little '^'. Albeit the code works well, I wish to know why this one character was exceptional in the cmd arguments?
I am using Windows Command Line for the shell.

---

An image of the output with 'p':
[calc.exe command line output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peBsd.png)

And with '^':
[output with caret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/200Y0.png)

Comment: Why did you tag it `C`?

Comment: What kind of shell are you using? My guess is that the shell is treating `^` as a special character before passing it to you. When you pass in `^`, what are the values in `argv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows shell (Batch script), a caret (`^`) is an escape character (see more here: [What does symbol ^ mean in Batch script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20342828/2602718)). So if you want it to be seen as a normal character by the shell, you need to escape it...with itself!

So you'd run:

```
calc.exe 3 ^^ 3
```

You can test this by using `echo` in the shell. You can run `echo te^st` to see what the shell treats it as, and then run `echo te^^st`.

---

Furthermore, you should add at least *some* error handling in your program to catch things like this sooner. For example, you could check `argc` to make sure the number of arguments passed match what you expect. You could add check around `s >> a >> b` to ensure that numbers were actually passed, etc...

Comment: This solved the problem. I guess I'll use p or something else but not a caret. Also, as you suggested, I added exception catching functionality and a few more operators too, and it looks good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't do this:

> ```
> strcat(strcat(argv[1], " "), argv[3])
> ```

You are overflowing the size of the buffer for `argv[1]`.

Instead use a `std::string` to correctly allocate the amount of memory needed to perform concatenation.

Comment: Fine, now I am using C++ strings and stoi() for the conversion. But it never showed a buffer overflow warning, so what is the size limit for argv[1]?

Comment: `stringstream` was fine for the conversion, although it's definitely easier to convert two numbers stored in separate `argv` elements independently instead of concatenating them and separating them again.  The size limit for `argv[1]` is the size of the string already in it when `main(argc, argv)` is called.