# What to do when we facing difficulty with git command "git reset --hard HEAD^"?

Tags: git, command-prompt

I am getting difficulty at the (git reset --hard HEAD^) when I press enter it is showing like (More?) What to do? how can  I delete that (love babbar and love eswar string is added) to get the HEAD to (new ) branch-->Index file is added. any help?

there are two images

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQE9c.png)

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B94I9.png)

[image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsiwj.png)

I tried to delete the 1 commit in the new branch, but it is not deleting and it is showing the both branches

Comment: I think your shell environment treats `^` as some special symbol and asks you for the continuation of the command on the next line. Moreover, `^` is usually used to select parent commits of the _merge_ commit. Try any of these: `git reset --hard [commit hash]` or `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

Comment: yeah, now it worked. by adding git reset --hard HEAD~1

Comment: even `~` by itself would work because it is just like `~1`. Being able to know how to escape `^` will come handy because `~` and `^` are not the same (they are _the same_ **only** when dealing _the first direct parent_).

Answer (score 0):

> The ^ symbol (also called caret or circumflex) is an escape character in Batch script.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20342902/1549818

Therefore the `^` needs to be escaped.
This can be done by using the escape character `^`, i.e. `^^`.