# How to split a master branch?

Tags: git, github, version-control, bitbucket

I found similar questions like one below :

> This question already has an answer here:
>
> [Change first commit of project with Git? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git?answertab=active#tab-top)
>
> [Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git)

Also, I found wonderful youtube video [how to split commit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3EzOz7e1ADI).

However, other sof questions or youtube didn't explain completely what need to do in order to split root commit.

Let me describe what I've : 
let say I have "master" branch with two commits:

1. root : "init" ce0418e
2. "Commit01" 8585a44

And I've another branch "anotherBranch" with three commits:

1. root : "init"  ce0418e
2. "testCommit01" 459ca66
3. "testCommit02" f9f0ba4

So I would like to split commit "init" ( it contains files: .gitignore ; README.md ; myClass )

I need that files .gitignore and README.md became the part of new "init" ( new root ) and myClass became another commit with message "myClass Splitted" and be the part of master branch.

From other sof questions I figure out that I should make the next steps :

1. `$git rebase -i --root`
2. in appeared new window and change from "pick" to "edit" in front of ce0418e "init" then esc then shift + ':' + 'wq'
3. Now I receive the message :

> Stopped at ce0418e.. init
>
> You can amend the commit now, with
>
> ```
> git commit --amend
> ```
>
> Once you are satisfied with your changes, run
>
> ```
> git rebase --continue
> ```

4. So I making `$git commit --amend` 
   and I receive the windows that states:

> init
>
> ```
>  Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
>  with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
>
>  Date:      Tue Dec 26 18:01:07 2016 +0100
>
> interactive rebase in progress; onto 11448c4
>  Last command done (1 command done):
>     edit ce0418e init
>  Next commands to do (2 remaining commands):
>     pick 8585a44 Commit01
>  You are currently editing a commit while rebasing branch 'master' on '11448c4'.
>
>
>  Initial commit
>
>  Changes to be committed:
>        new file:   .gitignore
>        new file:   README.md
>        new file:   myClass
> ```

Once again shortly, I need separate files: .gitignore and README.md from file: myClass 
But how ?

Obviously, I need to make some changes in this new window but what changes? 
I tried to make splitting through  `$git status` but it seems that it doesn't  work with root commit.

So my question is what should I do next ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your current git log structure like:

```
A---B     master
 \
   C---D  anotherBranch
```

> A for "init" ce0418e
>
> B for "Commit01" 8585a44
>
> C for "testCommit01" 459ca66
>
> D for  "testCommit02" f9f0ba4

And now you want to changes it to:

```
A’---B’---E   master
 \
   C’---D’    anotherBranch
```

> A’, B’, C’ and D’ only contain .gitignore and READMA.md (delete
>   myClass) and add a new commit for master branch contain myClass file.

So you can do as below:

1. Add a new commit for master branch by `git checkout master` and `git commit -am 'myClass Splitted'`
2. Rewrite master branch (A and B in graph) by `git rebase -i --root`.

In interactive windows, change A and B as edit, `edit ce0418e` and `edit 8585a44` and `pick E`.

When `stopped at ce0418e.. init`, **delete myClass** in working directory, and input `git add myClass` and `git rebase --continue`

For  `8585a44 (master|REBASE-i 2/3)`, also **delete myClass**, then input `git add myClass` and `git rebase --continue`

3. Rewrite anotherBranch by `git checkout anotherBranch` and `git rebase -i --root`.

In interactive window, change C and D to edit, `edit 459ca66` and `edit f9f0ba4`.

Then **delete myClass**, and do the same thing as the master branch.

Comment: thx for your response. "When stopped at ce0418e.. init, delete myClass in working directory" 1) Pls tell me what I do to delete myClass in working directory ? 2) According to your scheme do I correctly understand that I cannot split root in order that master branch looks like this :  A’--E---B' master ? Many thx for response.

Comment: For your questions: 1.Just in your local repo, find myClass and delete it. 2. Yes, you can make it in different order:A’-E-B’. In the interactive window you just need youe adjust the oder: `edit ce0418e`, `pick E` and `edit 8585a44`. `git rebase -i` is a powerful command, you can edit, re-order or delete a commit by it.