# Is it possible to select the first commit made in the repository in an interactive rebase?

Tags: git, rebase

I'm still learning git so don't have a clear idea.

I created a new repository and made 3 commits.

[image]

I want to rebase all the commits starting from the first one.

I do the command

```
git rebase -i 4a5244b
```

This is what's shown

[image]

The first commit `4a5244b` is not there. Is this just a special edge case with rebase where you can edit the first commit or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit the root commit in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's a special edge case because rebase asks you for a base commit and there is no ancestor of the root commit that you could give it. Fortunately, there is an option for this special case:

```
git rebase -i --root
```