# How to edit and push the change in initial (root) commit?

Tags: git, github, rebase

So, simply explaining my current situation:

- I kept pushing changes into origin master (no branches made yet)
- I decided to change the commit message of the initial commit of the Github Repository
- I did `$ git rebase -i --root` and change the commit message successfully
- I tried to force push by doing `$ git push --force`, but to get the following error:

  ```
  fatal: The current branch master has no upstream branch.  
  To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use 

  git push --set-upstream origin master.
  ```
- I tried to follow the instruction, but to get:

```
! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward) error: failed
to push some refs to 'git@github.com:BLAHBLAH.git' hint: Updates were
rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its
remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull
...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards'
in 'git push --help' for details.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change first commit of project with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git)

Comment: Duplicated, see  

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246208/change-first-commit-of-project-with-git
  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119480/edit-the-root-commit-in-git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only trying to modify the last commit - use ammend

```
# Change the latest commit message
git commit --amend --no-edit -m"<new message>
```

---

To push your changes:

Use this command:

```
# It will set up the "track" and will force the push
git push --set-upstream origin master -f
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, thanks! What does that -f change anyways?

Comment: `-f` = force the push and overwrite existing content